# Negative binomial regression - only for count data?

Tags: mixed-model, negative-binomial-distribution, count-data, zero-inflation

I've been pouring over statistics blogs over the last couple days to find a satisfactory answer to this, but I can't seem to find one, so I'll pose it to you in hope of a quick fix.

Basically, I'm trying to analyze the predictors of a charitable giving-type outcome variable, which takes the form of discrete, non-negative integers. The problem I have encountered is that this outcome variable, charitable contributions, is non-normally distributed, with a mode of 0 and decreasing spikes at "nice, round" numbers like 5, 10, 20 (as well as generally decreasing amounts in between). I'm a bit of a loss as to what type of model to fit to this data. I have used both a negative binomial mixed model (using glmer.nb in R) as well as a GLMM using a Gamma distribution (where I shifted all values by 1 to have an entirely non-zero scale), but they have produced vastly different results and I am not entirely sure whether either is a legitimate way to work with this data.

edit: I'm including the original histogram for clarity

[image]

Comment: What about zero inflated negative poisson?

Comment: I would have been shocked if your data was Gaussian.  While I conceptually understand your problem, it would be helpful if you added a histogram of your data.

Comment: I don't think Gamma distribution is appropriate, since you have integers. I would personally start with a Poisson and see if there is overdispersion (using family=quasipoisson). If there is overdispersion, quasi-Poisson or negative binomial might be appropriate. If you have zero inflation, then zero inflated poisson/negative binomial might be appropriate. Why have you decided on a mixed model? What is your random effect?

Comment: I decided on a mixed model because it is repeated measure data - each individuals had multiple opportunities to contribute

Comment: Although I am normally opposed to categorising variables this does seem a case where converting to multiples of five and truncating the infrequent ones in between might make life easier. You could then consider using a model suitable for ordered categorical outcomes.

Comment: @StudentT: What is zero inflated negative poisson? I guess you mean zero-inflated Poisson or negative binomial? I agree with mdewey to bin into [1], [2-5], [6-10] etc. You could also try to fit a "round number inflated" model and then still use a count distribution but that gets complicated.